# What's hotplug?

Tags: hot-plug

Many questions are tagged : [hot-plug](/questions/tagged/hot-plug)  . However , No wiki found in : [Tag info](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/hot-plug/info)

I've read this:

> Modularized USB drivers are loaded by the generic /sbin/hotplug
>   support in the ker- nel, which is also used for other hotplug devices
>   such as CardBus cards.

Therefore , Could we say that hotplug is the responsible on loading/unloading modules automatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/pending/hotplug.txt):

> The hotplug mechanism asynchronously notifies userspace when hardware is
> inserted, removed, or undergoes a similar significant state change.

There is an event variable for modules, called `DRIVER`, that suggests a driver for handling the hotplugged device.